# Populating form fields based on a selection made by user from a dropdown

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'm trying to create a 'name' editor for a user. So a user would select an existing name in the system via a dropdown that they wish to edit, once they've selected it two input fields would be populated with the existing first and last name and the user can edit them. I'm struggling to work out how to populate these two input fields with what was selected from the dropdown.

```
names: Name[] = [
   {
      firstName: 'firstname',
      lastName: 'lastname'
   },
   {
      firstName: 'firstname2',
      lastName: 'lastname2'
];

.ts
export class NameEditor {
   selected: Name;

   firstName = new FormControl();
   lastName = new FormControl();
}

.html
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selected">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let name of names" [value]="name">{{ name.firstName }}</mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
   // Where I want the two input fields filled with firstName and lastName

   <input matInput type="text" [value]="selected.firstName" [(ngModel)]="firstName"/>
</mat-form-field>
```

Looks something like that currently. So the selector selects a 'name' object that contains both first and last name, and then I want to push those values into the two form. The way it is currently is returning an error for the input field as "selected.firstName" is undefined. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That all looks fine, except for the fact that you're potentially binding a null value to the form controls when there isn't a selection made - which could potentially break the rendering.

I suggest using an `*ngIf` directive on the `mat-form-field` to detect when a selection is made:

```html
<mat-form-field *ngIf="!!selected">
    ....
</mat-form-field>
```